# Rollup optional input

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, rollup, rollupjs

Is there a way in Rollup to skip an input if it was not found? At the moment the build fails with `Error: Could not resolve entry module (src/index.js)` as soon as the file was not found.

I went through the documentation and searched around, but I can't seem to find an option or hook to achieve this. In the simplified example below, I would like to continue to the next `page.js` build when the `src/index.js` was not found.

```
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/esm/index.esm.js',
                format: 'esm',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/cjs/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            // ...
        ],
    },
    {
        input: 'page.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/esm/page.esm.js',
                format: 'esm',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/cjs/page.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            // ...
        ],
    },
];
```

Comment: wondering if you could create a function to return the exported array, and perform the necessary checks within that function to either push it on or off the array.

Comment: Interesting thought... Thanks! I use Lerna to execute rollup for each package. Maybe I could wrap the execution with a script that builds the configuration dynamically. I was hoping there would be a more elegant way to be honest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no idea if this will work or not, code to illstrate further what I'm talking about as a potential solution.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = 'src/index.js';

const config = [
{
        input: 'page.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/esm/page.esm.js',
                format: 'esm',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/cjs/page.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            // ...
        ],
}];

const determineFileExistsForConfig = () => {
  try {
     // if index exists, add to the config
     if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
       config.push({
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/esm/index.esm.js',
                format: 'esm',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/cjs/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            // ...
        ],
    });
     }
  } catch(err) {
    return config;
  }
}


const finalConfig = determineFileExistsForConfig();
export default finalConfig;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. I see Lerna passes the `$LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME` variable through, so I could potentially test against the specific package folder.